# single git repo push to multiple remotes

Tags: git, github

I have a Pelican static website that I want to push to GitHub pages. The way I have it set up, I have my configuration files (src) kept in one directory, and my actually HTML/CSS articles (pages) in another `content/` directory. I would like to have two separate remote repositories for each of these files using a single local repo. These are my remotes

```
$ git remote -v
pages   git@github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/Timothy-Pulliam.github.io.git (fetch)
pages   git@github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/Timothy-Pulliam.github.io.git (push)
src git@github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/linuxandchill-src.git (fetch)
src git@github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/linuxandchill-src.git (push)
```

However, when I publish an article, my `src/master` will be behind `HEAD/master` now. But I don't want src to include the latest commit, because I didn't make any configuration changes, only published a new article (my src repo is set to ignore output/ articles via .git/info/exclude)

```
(venv) tpulliam@lappy:~/code/linuxandchill-src$ ghp-import -m "Generate Pelican site" -r git@github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/Timothy-Pulliam.github.io.git -b master content/
(venv) tpulliam@lappy:~/code/linuxandchill-src$ git push pages master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 7.05 KiB | 2.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 1), reused 5 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To github.com:Timothy-Pulliam/Timothy-Pulliam.github.io.git
   c33a107..50cf76f  master -> master

commit 50cf76f051ff7190e5e52a8596b8f684c47fb57f (HEAD -> master, pages/master)
Author: Timothy Pulliam <timothy.dpulliam@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue May 14 10:29:32 2019 -0400

    Generate Pelican site

commit c33a107e2624455c70a854ed834c783c301182a6 (src/master, src/HEAD)
Author: Timothy Pulliam <timothy.dpulliam@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue May 14 10:10:09 2019 -0400

    Generate Pelican site
```

#### My question

Is what I am doing the right approach for what I wish to accomplish? I wish to avoid unnecessary commits and issues down the road. Here is the directory structure to give a better idea of what I am working with.

```
linuxandchill-src/
├── content
├── Makefile
├── output
├── pelicanconf.py
├── publishconf.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── tasks.py
└── venv
```

Comment: Do your two remotes have completely different content in each?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes they do. They are mutually exclusive. They only reason I don't have 2 local repositories (separate one in content/) is because it doesn't seem Pelican workflow is built around this. I guess I could make a content/.git, but I would need to make sure it does not get deleted which makes me nervous.

Comment: Then they probably shouldn't be remotes. You're probably wanting to look into dependancy management.

Comment: Are `git submodules` what you are looking for?

Comment: I believe sub modules are what I am looking for. Thank you